# Why my "Angular Material Components" Not Working?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am new to Angular 6 and Angular Material I tried creating one example to check Angular Material in the index.html with an ASP.NET CORE 1.1 application but its not working. My code is as follows.

**Index HTML:**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 6</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <my-app><h1>bacem</h1></my-app>

      <button mat-raised-button color="warn">Warn</button>
      <br />
      <div class="mat-app-background">
          <mat-slider></mat-slider>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**App Component ts:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './index.html',
    styleUrls: ['./styles.scss']
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

**App Module .ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AngMaterialModule } from './angmaterial';



@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule ,BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AngMaterialModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angmaterial .ts**

```js
import { MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule],
    exports: [MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule]
})

export class AngMaterialModule { }
```

**Result**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFMJS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rk6Y.png)

Comment: Hi ,Did you correctly install Angular material like this https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started and  so Can you please provide your code using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @core114 yesi installed correctly Angular material but how i provide my code using stackblitz ?

Comment: @core114 I did that in angmaterial .ts file but still the same problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**App Module .ts**
Should be a import  your  `MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule`

```
    import { MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material';

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

     @NgModule({
       imports: [
        BrowserModule ,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AngMaterialModule,
        MatButtonModule, 
        MatSliderModule],


    declarations: [AppComponent],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

and 
remove your

**angmaterial .ts** **to you include**

`MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule`

you need to generate new component `(ng g c yourcomponenetname)`

and put your html code use component 
remove your code part in **index.html**

**index.html**

> The main HTML page that is served when someone visits your site. Most
>   of the time you'll never need to edit it. The CLI automatically adds
>   all js and css files when building your app so you never need to add
>   any  or  tags here manually.

**The src folder**

> src
>
> **app**
>
> app.component.css
>
> app.component.html
>
> app.component.spec.ts
>
> app.component.ts
>
> app.module.ts

**assets**

> .gitkeep
>
> **environments**
>
> environment.prod.ts
>
> environment.ts
>
> browserslist
>
> favicon.ico
>
> index.html
>
> karma.conf.js
>
> main.ts
>
> polyfills.ts
>
> styles.css
>
> test.ts
>
> tsconfig.app.json
>
> tsconfig.spec.json
>
> tslint.json
>
> Your app lives in the src folder. All Angular components, templates,
>   styles, images, and anything else your app needs go here. Any files
>   outside of this folder are meant to support building your app.

you need to learn Anuar 6 [QuickStart with Angualar-6](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Comment: I didn't understand you please explain more i added   import { .., .. } from '@angular/material';  in my (App Module .ts) and it is the same problem !

Comment: @mecab1995 I know your issue, you are not generate any component try to understand this , read this https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: @mecab1995 follow the structure  you can easily do it , link here https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: my problem that i can't generate new component

Comment: run your terminal try like this `ng g component yourcomponentname` look cli https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Comment: @mecab1995 I think you are running ng serve in the directory where your Angular project is

Comment: i have this error this command can only be run inside of a cli project and my angular project is under wwwroot

Comment: @mecab1995 can you please create repository and share with me